# Passing Public IP from Terraform to Ansible in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: ansible, gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I am using a Terraform stage in GitLab CI/CD to deploy an EC2 instance. I know how to get the public IP of that instance once it's available for use throughout Terraform, but I'm not clear how to hop that over into an Ansible stage for configuration. Is there a way to output the public IP to an environment variable that can be made available to other stages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to pass Variables from one GitLab CI/CD job to another is to use the [`dotenv report artifact`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#artifactsreportsdotenv).

You simply put your variable in a file in the form `VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE`, and upload it as a specific type of artifact:

```yaml
job1:
  stage: stage1
  script:
    - echo "IP_ADDRESS='127.0.0.1'" >> .env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: .env

job2:
  stage: stage2
  script:
    - echo $IP_ADDRESS # echo's 127.0.0.1
```

Instead of a normal artifact that is downloaded in other jobs, the dotenv report type turns the variables within the file into Environment Variables for other jobs.